# How to specify (cross-browser) mouse pointer sets on leaflet control?

Tags: leaflet, style, css

Leaflet custom controls might be interactive, when the user can use the mouse on them to perform an action, or non-interactive, when they are used only to show information. This should affect the mouse pointer used for elements of the control (and possibly sub-elements of it for partly interactive controls).

What is the correct way to set those pointers for the control container and its sub-elements, if any (e.g. well defined css classes or else)?

Answer (score 3):

Building on the [answer by IvanSanchez](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/199866/9847), you can add a class to a layer:

```
var layer = L.featureGroup([]);
layer.style({'className': 'mask'})
```

then in CSS

```
path.leaflet-interactive.mask {cursor: crosshair}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is done in the Leaflet code by using the [`cursor` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor), see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/9c8590aebc9be74d0a2b71cf9c5e8a996d83b33a/dist/leaflet.css#L193

Comment: I believe the line number will change as master changes, it's currently found here https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/dist/leaflet.css#L204

Comment: @toms, you are correct. For future readers, here is a permalink: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/9c8590aebc9be74d0a2b71cf9c5e8a996d83b33a/dist/leaflet.css#L193